# VirtualBox 7 Screen Smearing After Upgrade

Tags: virtualbox

After upgrading to Virtualbox 7 (currently 7.0.2 r154219) I see this smearing effect when moving windows or using other effects that require a screen draw. This happens only when 3D acceleration is enabled.

[image]

- The host os is Windows 10 with an Nvidia 1060 GPU.
- The guest os was a preexisting Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS vm, however a clean install of Fedora 36 did the same.
- This was not an issue on the last of the 6.x versions. This issue only began after the upgrade.
- The smearing effect is only apparent after the screen size exceeds about 2k, although it can happen marginally sooner if I reduce the video memory available to the VM from 128MB to 64MB.
- Neither OS reports an error.
- The Guest Additions cd doesn't seem to affect this.
- *Kubuntu does not exhibit this behavior*

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox 7 is currently considered a *beta* version for *testing* and it has some glaring bugs and regressions.

If you don't need to use Windows 11 on a daily basis, please use VirtualBox 6.1.40 instead.